# What is the difference between "rolling back" versus "roll backing"?

Tags: grammar, differences

I read many articles on the internet in my free time. And sometime I see someone used "**rolling back**" in his statement. Another time I also see another guy used "**roll backing**". hmm

This makes me confused so much.

Are the both ways correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **to roll back**, * to roll* is the verb; *back* is an adverb. Therefore the correct continuous form is **rolling back**.

It is possible to grammatically use **roll backing**, where *backing* is a noun, and *roll* is still the verb. But this is extremely unlikely to be used - *backing* as a noun is uncommon, and where it does occur the *backing* is likely to be flat and hence not rollable. **roll backing** is therefore almost certainly a grammatical error.

However... **[rollback](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rollback?s=t)** as one word is a noun. A neologism could be to turn it into a verb, meaning "to create a rollback". You could then use *rollbacking* as its continuous form. This is not "standard" though.

Comment: Reminded me of the day in school when "stand upping" was used by someone I couldn't stop laughing :). Nice explanation; +1.

Comment: So I shouldn't use [roll backing](https://www.amazon.com/Hollingsworth-and-Vose-Tearaway-backing/dp/B003R3FKWA) on my next needlepoint project??

Comment: @HotLicks - I did say "extremely unlikely", not "impossible"...